# How do I open a new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[How do I open a new project in Android Studio?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl0gj.png)
I'm trying to open a new project
But instead of a window of quick opening
I get this screen
The project opens differently than usual

Has something gone wrong with definitions?
How do I get to a "quick opening" window
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: In android studio Goto File->New->New Project

Comment: There's an error message at the bottom of your screen  - `Required plugin "Android Support" is disabled`. Go to `File > Settings > Plugins`, is there a tick mark next to `Android Support`?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your screen there are several error messages related to loading plugins, most notably:

> Required plugin "Android Support" is disabled

[image]

I would bet that this is why you are seeing a different *New Project* dialog as your copy of Android Studio can no longer use Android-related functionality. In order to re-enable this plugin, go to `File -> Settings -> Plugins` and ensure that the entry for `Android Support` and everything else Android-related is checked.

[image: Android Studio plugin screen]

You may need to restart Android Studio once you've done this.

Answer (score -4):

I think you're already in a new project. Look at the paths in the top of the screen shot. It's asking you to set up the parameters of the project, after which, you can save the project with a correct name. You look to have tried this 22 times prior to this screen shot, you're in "untitled23" for your project name.